# Adding a method to prototype of an object literal

Tags: javascript, prototype

If I try to add a method to prototype of an object, it doesn't work with this:

```
const dog = {
    color: 'black',
    bread: 'Spitz',
}

dog.prototype.hello = function() { // Doesn't work
    return `Hello, I'm a ${black} dog.`
}

console.log(dog);
```

But it works if I use `__proto__` instead of prototype:

```
const dog = {
    color: 'black',
    bread: 'Spitz',
}

dog.__proto__.hello = function() { // Works
    return `Hello, I'm a ${black} dog.`
}

console.log(dog);
```

Why is that?

Comment: The prototype for dog would be `Object.prototype` in this case. You could see what result editing that would have!

Comment: You don't need a prototype for an object literal. Simply put your `hello` method directly in the object.